# How do I release objects from a jobjectArray?

Tags: c++, c, java-native-interface

I've got the following code:

```c
jobjectArray objects; //function argument, actually a byte[][]
jbyteArray* arrays = malloc(sizeof(jbyteArray), 2); // Assume 2
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    arrays[i] = (jbyteArray)env->GetObjectArrayElement(objects, i);
}

// Do stuff with arrays.

// Do I have to do this?
// for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
//     env->DeleteLocalRef(arrays[i]);
// }
free(arrays);
```

Is this enough to avoid leaking memory / keeping stray references? Or should I also be calling DeleteLocalRef?

edit:
I did find this reference at the help for [IBM SDK for Java](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v5r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.50/diag/understanding/jni_refs.html) which states that they are automatically cleaned up when the function returns to Java. But if there is no automatic garbage collection, references might leak.

Comment: is this C **OR** C++?

Comment: C++ actually, but that should not really be relevant to the question. I know that in C++ the use of malloc / free can also be replaced by using a std::vector<>

Comment: The JNI subsystem should handle cleaning up the parameters passed to you. The sample you linked provided cleanup for objects allocated *within* your JNI proc. (i.e. what *you* allocated) and were *not* passing back.

Comment: I understand that. I'm not trying to cleanup the actual arguments that were passed to the function. I think that since the (references to) jobjects returned from the GetObjectArrayElement() call are allocated on the stackframe for this function, that they will be cleaned up automatically by the JVM once I return. It's confusing since you have to explicitly release primitive array elements, but (apparently?) not object array elements.